# AngularFire: How to bind data to the $scope?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to learn Firebase, and finding that MongoDB and Firebase are different. :-)

To make a simple "Likes" counter, in the view I have:

```
<span>Likes: {{post.likes}}</span>
<form ng-submit="upLike(post)">
  <input type="submit" value="Up"></input>
</form>
```

In MongoDB this controller works:

```
$scope.upLike = function(post) {
  console.log("Liked!");
  var likes = post.likes || 0;
  post.likes += 1;
  $http.put('http://localhost:8080/api/blogDB/' + post._id, post).then(function(response) { // UPDATE
    console.log("Upliked.");
  }, function(response) {
    console.log("Invalid URL");
  });
}
```

`$scope.posts` is an array. `post` is an object in the array.
MongoDB pulls the `_id` from the object (`post`), then updates that record in the collection (`posts`) with the new data.

With Firebase I can't do `$http.put`. Instead I have to bind the new data to $scope, and it'll bind to Firebase.

```
app.controller('ShowController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray',
function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

  var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
  $scope.posts = $firebaseArray(ref);

  $scope.upLike = function(post) {
    console.log("Liked!");
    var likes = post.likes || 0;
    post.likes += 1;
    // What goes here instead of $http.put?
  }
```

`$scope.post.likes += 1;` doesn't work because `post` is not an array on `$scope`.

`$scope.posts.likes += 1;` doesn't work because I'm not identifying which post is getting a like.

Should I use `ng-click` instead of `ng-submit`? I could make the view increment likes, but I don't see how to attach this data to the $scope. Should I do something with `ng-model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in your `$scope.upLike` function you want to call [`$firebaseArray.$save(recordOrIndex)`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html):

```
$scope.upLike = function(post) {
    post.likes += 1;
    $scope.posts.$save(post);
};
```

If you were using a `$firebaseObject`, then you would call `object.$save()`.

Edit: yes you should also probably use `ng-click` instead of `ng-submit`. You only really need a form when you're collecting multiple inputs at once, or when you want to take advantage of Angular's form validation. Otherwise a button does just fine.

Comment: Awesome! If you're using `$firebaseObject` elsewhere, also check out the [three-way object bindings](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-objects), where you don't need to call the `$save()` method on changes. Pretty cool.

Comment: I used three-way object binding on a tic-tac-toe game a couple months ago. Is three-way binding only for Firebase objects. not arrays? Maybe that's why I'm getting confused!

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure it's only for objects, you have to call save/remove/etc manually for arrays. The docs don't mention why this is though, I would guess performance reasons.